# How do I remove the Page Content zone from blank web part template?

Tags: 2013

As the title suggests.  This space isn't reclaimed even if you haven't put anything in it so all of my web part pages have a 2" thick white strip across the top of the middle of the page.

I have managed to remove the 3 lines where "welcome-content" is but strangely when I do so it works.. but when I try to edit the page the ribbon controls all get disabled!  Whether this is a bug or a dependency I'm not sure.

Can anyone help please?
thanks!

EDIT:  Oh I give up trying to paste code into the browser!
If you open a blank web part page in SP designer 2013 and go to line 31 it's this section I was referring to

```
    <div class="welcome-content">
        <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" HasInitialFocus="True" MinimumEditHeight="5px" runat="server"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced something similar before, where I have to press backspace and delete until the 'blank' space was removed. Then I had to quickly unfocus the section so that SharePoint wouldn't automatically reinsert the 'blank' space before leaving the section. Save the page and the space was gone. Strange strange SharePoint...

Hope that works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Add a script editor on your page with the following script:

```
< style >
.article-content, .welcome-content {display: none;}
.article-content, .welcome-content {margin: 0px !Important; border-spacing: 0px !important;}
.ms-core-pageTitle {margin: 0px !Important; border-spacing: 0px !important;}
div.article, div.welcome {padding: 0px !Important;}
< /style >
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I fixed it.  The page layout had a links section that was creating the space. :-)

***Or Else Reference this [Link](http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/npatterson/archive/2014/09/05/sharepoint-2013-fixing-blank-web-part-page-spacing/) for Fixing Blank Web Part Page spacing***